# Move files into folders based on their names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some files in the form:

> ```
> filename1 1.ext
> filename1 2.ext
> filename1 3.ext
> ...
> filename2 1.ext
> filename2 100.ext
> ...
> filename20 1.ext
> filename20 15.ext
> (etc.)
> ```

...where `filename` can contain spaces.

And I want to move them to folder `filename1`, `filename2`, etc., respectively.

I know I can do a `for` loop `for %%i in (*.ext) do` and remove the extension with `set folder=%%~ni`. So what I am missing is how to remove everything after the space just before the number, and get only `filename1`, for example.

I also know I can split variable `folder`, but in this case I do not know by at which character I need to split, although I know it will be a space followed by a number.

So basically, I want something like this:

```
@echo off
set folder=

for %%i in (*.ext) do set folder=%%~ni & set folder=getfoldernamefromvariablefoldersomehow & mv %%i %folder%
```

Comment: `for %i in (*.ext) do @for /F %I in ("%~ni") do @echo %I "%~i"` in `cmd` prompt could navigate to a solution?

Comment: There is no `mv` command, it is called [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to all of you for your comments. Finally, i was able to get a solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_source=C:\Users\kurok_000\Downloads"
set "_target=C:\Users\kurok_000\YandexDisk\Mangas"

for /f "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%_source%\*.7z"') do (  
    call :fixNames "%%f" %_source%
)

for /f "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%_source%\*.7z" ^| findstr /r /i /c:" [0123456789][0123456789]*\.7z$"') do (
    set "file=%%f"
    call :split last rest "%%f"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    2> nul mkdir "!_target!\!rest!"
    move /y "!_source!\!file!" "!_target!\!rest!" >nul
    echo moved %%f to !_target!\!rest!
    endlocal
)
endlocal
exit /b

:split  rtn_last  rtn_rest  val_string
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "res=" & set "str=%~3"
:loop
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%i in ("%str%") do (
    if "%%j"=="" (
        set "res=%%i"
    ) else (
        set "str=%%j"
        goto :loop
    )
)
:quit
set "str=%~3|"
call set "str=%%str: %res%|=%%"
(
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%res%"
    set "%~2=%str:^^=^%"
)
exit /b

:fixNames _file _folder
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE=%1"
set "FILE=%file:~1,-1%"
set "folder=%2"

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%FILE%") do (
    set filename=!FILE:%%B=!%%~xB
    )
if not "%filename%"=="%FILE%" (rename "!folder!\!FILE!" "!filename!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.ext" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :sub1 "%%a" %%a
)

GOTO :EOF

:sub1
SET "filename=%~1"
:subloop
SHIFT
SET "numname=%~1"
IF NOT "%~2"=="" GOTO subloop
CALL SET "dirname=%%filename: %numname%=%%
ECHO( MD "%sourcedir%\%dirname%" 2>nul
ECHO( MOVE "%sourcedir%\%filename%" "%sourcedir%\%dirname%\%numname%"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Perform a directory list of the required files in basic form without directorynames. Send the full fulename in quotes and without to the subroutine `sub1`.

In the subroutine, save the source filename in `filename` then shift each parameter supplied until there is no second parameter; the value in `numname` must then be the last or required filename.

Remove `numname` with a leading space from `filename` to get the required subdirectoryname, make that subdirectory and move the file.

[edit in the light of comment]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.ext" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :sub1 "%%a" %%a
)

GOTO :EOF

:sub1
SET "filename=%~1"
SET "destdirname=%~2"
:subloop
SHIFT
SET "numname=%~1"
IF NOT "%~2"=="" GOTO subloop
CALL SET "dirname=%%filename: %numname%=%%
ECHO( MD "%sourcedir%\%destdirname%" 2>nul
ECHO( MOVE "%sourcedir%\%filename%" "%sourcedir%\%destdirname%\%numname%"
GOTO :eof
```

It's difficult to scry your intentions when you give no example.

`destdirname` is set to the second parameter on entering `sub1` which will be the first group of characters before the first space.

the `md` does not need to be gated since the `2>nul` will suppress the `directory exists` error message.

Comment: hi, this has a problem when the file name is something like "filename 12 etc.ext". It moves the files to folder "filename 12" instead of folder "filename"...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that does what you want. It splits off the last <kbd>SPACE</kbd> followed by numerals from the file name and uses the remaining string as the name of the destination directory of the movement.

This approach handles all valid characters for file names properly, even `^`, `&`, `%`, `!`, `(` and `)`. It can even handle file names that contain <kbd>SPACE</kbd> plus numerals plus `.ext` again correctly.

So here is the code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=."
set "_TARGET=."

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B "%_SOURCE%\*.ext" ^| findstr /R /I /C:" [0123456789][0123456789]*\.ext$"
') do (
    set "FILE=%%F"
    call :SPLIT LAST REST "%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    2> nul mkdir "!_TARGET!\!REST!"
    ECHO move /Y "!_SOURCE!\!FILE!" "!_TARGET!\!REST!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:SPLIT  rtn_last  rtn_rest  val_string
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "RES=" & set "STR=%~3"
    :LOOP
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%I in ("%STR%") do (
        if "%%J"=="" (
            set "RES=%%I"
        ) else (
            set "STR=%%J"
            goto :LOOP
        )
    )
    set "STR=%~3|"
    call set "STR=%%STR: %RES%|=%%"
    (
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%RES%"
        set "%~2=%STR:^^=^%"
    )
    exit /B
```

After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually move any files. Unless you remove the `/Y` option from the `move` command, files become overwritten without prompt. To suppress summary messages (like `1 file(s) moved.`), add `> nul` to the `move` command line. Note that any prompt was also hidden then in case you removed the `/Y` option.

Comment: Hi, i've executed it but with no results. If i run `dir /B "%_SOURCE%\*.ext" ^| findstr /R /I /C:" [0123456789][0123456789]*\.ext$"`, i got the message: `El modificador no es válido: "I". (invalid modifier (?))`

Comment: I realized that this works fine, except when the filename have things after the number, i.e., "file name 12 extra things.ext". It should move to folder "\file name"

Comment: If you run `dir ... | findstr ...` separately outside of the `for /F` loop you need to remove the `^` in front of `|`...

Comment: Of course `file name 12 extra things.ext` is not moved into folder `file name`, because your question does not say to do so! You should not change your requirements, because already supplied answers may become invalid then! So how to distinguish between the `extra things` part and the numeric part? what if this part is also purely numeric? and what if `the file name` also contains a purely numeric part? which one is to be kept, and which one is to be removed from the file name?

Comment: Hi, yeah! I realized after i posted. Sorry about that. If we consider a file named `filename 123 extra.ext`, `filename` can contain spaces and symbol `'`, but not numbers. `extra` can contain anything. It woudn't bother me if for making use of your already working solution, getting rid of the `extra` part of the file name (included the space before), leaving just `filename 123.ext` (numbers never repeat)

Comment: If the `file name` part does certainly not contain numerals, you could use something like `set "FILE=file name 12 extra things.ext" & (for /F "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%A in ("!FILE!") do set "EXTRA=%%B") & set "FIRST=!FILE:*%EXTRA%=!"`, although this could fail under particular circumstances...

Comment: It was not meant to be inserted into the script, it was just intended to give an idea of a possible solution; (I just noticed that the last `set` command must be stated in a separate line instead of being appended with `&`...)

Comment: You're welcome! So basically you want to extract the first numeric part enclosed within spaces, right? I would suggest you try it on your own first, and if stuck, come back here and ask a new question...